# Laravel get N level hierarachy table dropdown in select option

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am using LARAVEL 7 with MySQL back-end.

I have a topics table with columns id, name, and parent. Here, parent is foreign-key of the column Id. The data in table is as below :

[image]

i am trying to show those topics names like this

```
    fractions 
- fractions > introduction to fractions 
- fractions > introduction to fractions > What are fractions and its purpose? 
- fractions > introduction to fractions > Fractions as division 
- fractions > Representation of fractions 
- fractions > Representation of fractions > How to represent a fraction - Area Models
```

here is my ajax call where i am showing all topics :

```
function getSubjectsTopics(subject_id)
{
    if(subject_id) {
        loading_show();
    axios.get("/master/topic/get-topic-by-subject-id/" + subject_id)
        .then(function(response) {
            var optionHtml = '<option value="0">Parent</option>';
            if(response.data.status) {
                $.each(response.data.subject_topics, function(i,v) {
                    optionHtml += `<option value="${v.id}">${v.name}</option>`;

                 });

            }
            $("#ddl_topic_type").html(optionHtml).attr('disabled', false).select2();
            loading_hide();
            //console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            loading_hide();
            console.log(error);
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Something went wrong!'
            })
        })
    } else {
        $("#ddl_topic_type").attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

here is the function from controller where i am getting all topics:

```
public function getTopicsBySubjectID($subject_id)
{
    $topics = Topic::where("subject_id", $subject_id)->get(['id', 'name']);

    $sub_topics = Topic::with('childTopics')->parent()->get(['id', 'name']);

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'subject_topics' => $topics, 'sub_topics' => $sub_topics], 200);
}
```

here is  my model function where i am getting only topics with one level only:

```
 public function parentTopic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Topic', 'parent_id');
}



public function scopeParent($query)
{
    return $query->whereNull('parent_id');
}
```

Now in my topic dropdown i am getting topics like this :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Can anyone help me how can i change the hierarchy..thanks in advance.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XN5Z.png